# can't find answer, Jersey 404 error, when go to web page rest/*, git code https://gitlab.com/Kaidstor/job-access

Tags: java, git, tomcat, jersey

[image: that error seems]

file name: pom.xml

**I think that mistakes can be here**

stack overflow don't give me good answer, I don't know what I most to write that my question come in pull peoples questions. If you need more info write comments I answer as I can.

Use my git or write me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>StudentChecker</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-M1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.28</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    </project>
```

file name: web.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <display-name>Students checker</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>web</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/Student</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
    </web-app>
```

**don't know what to say, pls help**

file name:CheckPersonService.java

```
package web;
```

```
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;

    @Path("check")
    public class CheckPersonService {
    @GET
    public String checkPreson(){
        return "Simple string";
    }
    }
```

*may be I put not right path?! and check cannot be used?*

Comment: 1. You're trying to access the endpoint /checkPerson, but the endpoint is /check. 2. In your web.xml, the url-mapping is /rest/*, but you do not have this in the Url. So it should be /StudentChecker-1.0/rest/check

Comment: same problem The requested resource [/StudentChecker-1.0/rest/check] is not available

Comment: Everything you’ve posted looks good. Can you please try with Tomcat 9?

Comment: I try to use 9.0.43 but it send me same problem..

Comment: yes, it solved)

Answer (score 0):

As say Paul Samsotha I use 9.0.43 tomcat and it start to work, I include it into intelij idea, before I do it, it can't work